# Can't get Apache httpd on CentOS to core dump

Tags: linux, apache, debugging, centos

I've been experiencing the following error flooding my `error_log` and I'm trying to enable core dumps so that I can debug this error and find the cause.

```
[core:notice] [pid 32710] AH00052: child pid 32759 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

**Steps I've taken to enable core dumps**

1. Edited `httpd.conf` and added: `CoreDumpDirectory /tmp`
2. Ran `ulimit -c unlimited`
3. Edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` and added the lines below
4. Reloaded the settings using `sysctl -p`

```
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
kernel.core_pattern = /tmp
fs.suid_dumpable = 2
```

**However**

So far this has had no effect and core dumps still do not run?

What I expect is to see is:

```
[core:notice] [pid 2921] AH00051: child pid 18853 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump insttead of /tmp and hope you have correct permissions
and restart apache